# Hbase: Migration from standalone mode to Fully distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I want to if its possible to migrate from standalone mode to fully distributed mode in Hbase.I have some data in standalone mode  which i would like to persist during migration.
Please help.

Comment: Somebody please help here.

Comment: Thanks Sourav .. but my question is how ?

Comment: could you post current configuration from hbase-site.xml and regionserver file

Comment: I have not configured the distributed environment yet .. Here is my hbase-site.xml from standalone mode :-
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/vimal/HBASE/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/vimal/HBASE/zookeeper</value>
  </property>

</configuration>

Comment: try to start it in pseudo distributed mode first .

in hbase-site.xml add
<property> 
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name> 
<value>2181</value> 
</property> 

<property> 
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name> 
<value>true</value> 
</property>
<property> 
<name>hbase.master</name> 
<value>your ip or localhost</value> 
</property>
<property> 
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name> 
<value>yourip or localhost</value> 
</property>

In regionservers file add
your ip 
and start hbase cluster

Comment: Hi Sourav,
As per your suggestion , i have moved to pseudo distributed mode , but now i have lost my data of standalone mode.How do i recover it ?

Comment: have you used the same value for root.dir , if yes go to that dir and check , data is still there?

Comment: i tried the same , i did not loose any data

Comment: I have changed the value of root.dir as now its pseudo distributed mode so i have to make root.dir point to an instance of HDFS.

Comment: Vimal , your root dir should be some , only then you would be able to see the data . Because table is stored in your root dir only. 
You can try to copy data from your local dir to hdfs location to check whether it works or not

Answer (score 4):

Quite old question but recently I encountered same problem and solved it using following steps:

**In standalone mode**

Export table you want to migrate:

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver export table_name /local/path/table_name_backup
```

**In pseudodistributed/distributed mode**

Copy table in hdfs using hadoop:

```
./bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /local/path/table_name_backup/ table_name_backup
```

Import data using hbase:

```
./bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver import table_name table_name_backup
```

Remove old data from hdfs using hadoop:

```
./bin/hadoop dfs -rmr table_name_backup
```

U might want to check number of rows before and after migration to check if everything went according to plan:

```
./bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver rowcounter table_name
```